# Finding largest number of location IDs per hour from each zone

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am using scala with spark and having a hard time understanding how to calculate the maximum count of pickups from a location corresponding to each hour. Currently I have a df with three columns (Location,hour,Zone) where Location is an integer, hour is an integer 0-23 signifying the hour of the day and Zone is a string. Something like this below:

```
Location    hour     Zone
   97        0        A 
   49        5        B
   97        0        A
   10        6        D
   25        5        B
   97        0        A 
   97        3        A
```

What I need to do is find out for each hour of the day 0-23, what zone has the largest number of pickups from a particular location

So the answer should look something like this:

```
  hour     Zone    max_count
   0        A          3
   1        B          4
   2        A          6
   3        D          1
   .        .          .
   .        .          .
   23       D          8
```

What I first tried was to use an intermediate step to figure out the counts per zone and hour

```
val df_temp = df.select("Location","hour","Zone")
                .groupBy("hour","Zone").agg(count($"Location").alias("count"))
```

This gives me a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  hour     Zone      count
   3        A          5
   8        B          9
   3        B          2
   23       F          8
   23       A          1
   23       C          4
   3        D          12
   .        .          .
   .        .          .
```

I then tried doing the following:

```
val df_final = df_temp.select("hours","Zone","count")
                     .groupBy("hours","Zone").agg(max($"count").alias("max_count")).orderBy($"hours")
```

This doesn't do anything except just grouping by hours and zone but I still have 1000s of rows. I also tried:

```
val df_final = df_temp.select("hours","Zone","count")
                     .groupBy("hours").agg(max($"count").alias("max_count")).orderBy($"hours")
```

The above gives me the max count and 24 rows from 0-23 but there is no Zone column there. So the answer looks like this:

```
hour       max_count
  0           12
  1           15
  .            .
  .            .
  23           8
```

I would like the Zone column included so I know which zone had the max count for each of those hours. I was also looking into the window function to do rank but I wasn't sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spark window functions for this task.

At first you can group by the data to get a count of number of zones.

```
val df = read_df.groupBy("hour", "zone").agg(count("*").as("count_order"))
```

Then create a window to partition the data by hour and order it by total count. Then you have to calculate the rank over this partition of data.

```
val byZoneName = Window.partitionBy($"hour").orderBy($"count_order".desc)
val rankZone = rank().over(byZoneName)
```

This will perform the operation and list out the rank of all the zones grouped by hour.

```
val result_df = df.select($"*", rankZone as "rank")
```

The output will be something like this:

```
+----+----+-----------+----+
|hour|zone|count_order|rank|
+----+----+-----------+----+
|   0|   A|          3|   1|
|   0|   C|          2|   2|
|   0|   B|          1|   3|
|   3|   A|          1|   1|
|   5|   B|          2|   1|
|   6|   D|          1|   1|
+----+----+-----------+----+
```

You can then filter out the data with rank 1.

```
result_df.filter($"rank" === 1).orderBy("hour").show()
```

You can check my code here:
https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5114666914683617/1792645088721850/4927717998130263/latest.html

Answer (score 2):

After generating the dataframe with per-hour/zone "count", you could generate another dataframe with per-hour "max_count" and join the two dataframes on "hour" and "max_count":

```
val df = Seq(
  (97, 0, "A"),
  (49, 5, "B"),
  (97, 0, "A"),
  (10, 6, "D"),
  (25, 5, "B"),
  (97, 0, "A"),
  (97, 3, "A"),
  (10, 0, "C"),
  (20, 5, "C")
).toDF("location", "hour", "zone")

val dfC = df.groupBy($"hour", $"zone").agg(count($"location").as("count"))

val dfM = dfC.groupBy($"hour".as("m_hour")).agg(max($"count").as("max_count"))

dfC.
  join(dfM, dfC("hour") === dfM("m_hour") && dfC("count") === dfM("max_count")).
  drop("m_hour", "count").
  orderBy("hour").
  show
// +----+----+---------+
// |hour|zone|max_count|
// +----+----+---------+
// |   0|   A|        3|
// |   3|   A|        1|
// |   5|   B|        2|
// |   6|   D|        1|
// +----+----+---------+
```

Alternatively, you could perform the per-hour/zone `groupBy` followed by a `Window` partitioning by "hour" to compute "max_count" for the `where` condition, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.
  groupBy($"hour", $"zone").agg(count($"location").as("count")).
  withColumn("max_count", max($"count").over(Window.partitionBy("hour"))).
  where($"count" === $"max_count").
  drop("count").
  orderBy("hour")
```